# Manipulate all elements of an array at once

Tags: java, arrays

I'm assuming the answer is no, but I'm looking for a way to manipulate all of the elements in an array at once, rather than writing a loop. For example, the code below creates two arrays and then errors. Obviously the commented lines don't work, but I would like to avoid writing a loop for every function I need to apply.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] foo = new int[10];
        int[] bar = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            bar[i]=i;
        }
        foo += bar; // want to add elements of these arrays pairwise. this fails.
        bar += 1; // want to add 1 to each element of the array. this also fails.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo));
    }
}
```

Comment: using raw arrays is not how to write modern idiomatic Java, there is a reason that is a robust `Collections` framework that has `List`, `Set` and `Map` interfaces.

Comment: With what objective? how about recursive functions?

Comment: What exact values would you like in `foo` after your operation? What *exactly* do you mean pairwise?

Comment: Yeah really probably the best/most straightforward way to do this is just loop. If you're that concerned about appearance you could add an extension method or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operation on the set of individual elements of a java array will require a loop, whether it's explicit (for loop) or implicit (map function). You could certainly write an object that would exhibit the behavior you're looking at in your foo and bar lines, to hide the loop, but it would still be there. (and of course you wouldn't be able to use the operator overloading and make the + operator part of the equation happen - it would have to be a method call)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8, you could use lambda expressions, although it will probably be less clear than just looping. That would look like this:

```
final int barFinal = bar;
final int fooFinal = foo;
foo = Arrays.stream(bar).map(i -> barFinal[i] + fooFinal[i]).toArray();
bar = Arrays.stream(bar).map(i -> i + 1).toArray();
```

This works for your specific example, but would be difficult to do on more complicated or arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

**This will not override the array, Instead it get what you need every time it fetches.**

```
  List<Integer> bar= new ArrayList<Integer>(){
      @Override
      public Integer get(int i){
          return super.get(i)+foo[i];
      }
  };
  bar.addAll(Arrays.asList(bar));
```

`bar.get(count)` will get what you need.

Comment: I believe you need `super.get(i)` instead of `this.get(i)` so you don't recurse infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Even there's looks like existing an special operator meet your requirement, but using loop in essence. As the structure for Set need to handle element in loop. Even I haven't heard a structure can do such operation.